# Accessing the 'arguments' property of a function is not allowed in strict mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get an Angularjs app running but I keep getting the following silent exceptions:
"imageService.getImages().success.arguments Accessing the 'arguments' property of a function is not allowed in strict mode" 
and
"imageService.getImages().success.caller Accessing the 'caller' property of a function or arguments object is not allowed in strict mode"
when creating any function in my javascript file even though I am not using the "strict mode".

The environment is VS 2013 ASP.NET web with index.html and AngularJS.

The code segment below creates the functions and throws the silent exceptions  at runtime and nothing is displayed:

```
//app.js
angular.module('photoBrowser', [])
    .service('imageService', function($http){
        return {
            getImages: function () {
                return $http.get("/photos.json", { responseType: "JSON" });
            }
        }
    })

    .controller('photoList', function ($scope, imageService) {
        imageService.getImages().success(function (result) {
            $scope.images = result;
        })
    })
```

Comment: Please provide the code :)

Comment: The `.arguments` property is poisoned on functions that are themselves in strict mode, not functions that are called from strict mode code. And even in sloppy mode you should have no reason to access it?!

Comment: Neil, That's all the javascript code there is in the project.